# How to disable panel in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, panel

I am currently using Bootstrap panel but am not able to disable the panel. I've added disabled class and its not taking. How do I disable the panel in Bootstrap using jquery or css. Below i have pasted the code.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default disabled" id='result' disabled>
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1 
            </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
               Collapsible Group Item #2 
            </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up  pull-right"></i>
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
              Collapsible Group Item #3 
            </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please can post with an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: @ccdiego5 http://jsfiddle.net/hqjk2e1r/

Comment: Heads up - I believe you should add in the jQuery file before the bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to disable a collapse or 'show collapse' functionality in a bootstrap, then you can use `hide.bs.collapse` and  `show.bs.collapse` events.

Example:
Add following HTML to invoke disable function!

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnDisable">click to disable</button>
```

*Then following JS does the trick.*

```
    var disablePanel = false;  //or falsey value
    $("#accordion").on('hide.bs.collapse show.bs.collapse',  PanelEvent);

    function PanelEvent(e){
       $self = (this);  
       if(disablePanel){    
       e.preventDefault();    // this is the trick
       console.log("panel should not behave");
      }
     else{
       console.log("panel opens or closes!");
      }
     };

  $("#btnDisable").click(function(e){
    disablePanel = true; //or truthy value
    console.log(goAhead);
  });
```

**Note**: The important part is to utilize `hide.bs.collapse` and `show.bs.collapse` events. The above example is just one way to utilize those events.

**Warning**: `hidden.bs.collapse` and `shown.bs.collapse` events are fired after accordion is collapsed so these events won't work to disable panel[accordion].

Answer (score 0):

I've got a little trick I just used today at work :

just empty the data-toggle attribute.

I don't know if it's neat or not but it works

```js
  $("#disablePanels").on("click",function(){
 $(".accordion-toggle").attr("data-toggle", "");
  });
  
    $("#enablePanels").on("click",function(){
  $(".accordion-toggle").attr("data-toggle", "collapse");
  });
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default" id='result'>
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1 
            </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down  pull-right"></i>
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
               Collapsible Group Item #2 
            </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up  pull-right"></i>
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
              Collapsible Group Item #3 
            </a><i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></i>
          </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="disablePanels" style="width:200px;margin-right:10px;">Disable panels</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="enablePanels" style="width:200px;margin-right:10px;">Enable panels</button>
```